# Need to add fields of another serializer to the serializer. I pass only id and amount, and json should return in response

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

There is a recipe serializer that needs to receive ingredients, which is also handled by another serializer. The recipe and ingredient models are connected through a Many-to-Many relationship. Only the ingredient's ID and quantity need to be passed, and that's what I receive in response.

```json
{
    "ingredients": [
        "Invalid type. The primary key value was expected, dict was received."
    ]
}
```

I need to somehow override the create method differently.

```py
# serializers.py

class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'measurement_unit')

class RecipeCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Tag.objects.all()
    )
    author = UserSerializer
    ingredients = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Ingredient.objects.all()
    )
    image = Base64ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('author',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
        ingredients = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for tag in tags:
            current_tag, status = Tag.objects.get_or_create(**tag)
            TagsInRecipe.objects.create(tag=current_tag, recipe=recipe)

        for ingredient in ingredients:
            current_ingredient, status = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(**ingredient)
            IngredientsInRecipe.objects.create(
                ingredient=current_ingredient,
                recipe=recipe,
                amount=ingredient['amount']
            )
        return recipe
```

expected

```json
{
    "id": 0,
    "tags": [
        {}
    ],
    "author": {
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "id": 0,
    "username": "string",
    "first_name": "Name",
    "last_name": "Last Name",
    "is_subscribed": false
    },
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "potato",
            "measurement_unit": "g",
            "amount": 1
        }
    ],
    "is_favorited": true,
    "is_in_shopping_cart": true,
    "name": "string",
    "image": "http://example.org/media/recipes/images/image.jpeg",
    "text": "string",
    "cooking_time": 1
}
```

Comment: When are you getting this error while creating a Recipe?